# Query strings with special characters

Tags: url, asp-classic, query-string, encode

How I can pass a query string with special characters?

For example I need to pass "&" inside my query string as below:

```
../solrresults.asp?mode=search&data=M & S
```

Comment: Have you tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`

Comment: For classic ASP, you can use `Server.UrlEncode()` Function...

Comment: Server.UrlEncode() works for most of the special characters.For "%" it is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Server.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx):

> URLEncode converts characters as follows:
>   Spaces ( ) are converted to plus signs (+).
>   Non-alphanumeric characters are escaped to their hexadecimal representation.

Use it this way;

```
<a href="page2.asp?name=<%= Server.URLEncode(sName) %>">here</a>
```

Comment: My code is in classic ASP, so I would like to see a way in ASP itself

Answer (score -1):

After your comments, here is a solution in various scripting languages:

There are different versions available for each scripting language. Here is a reference from w3schools:

> In JavaScript you can use the encodeURI() function. PHP has the
>   rawurlencode() function and ASP has the Server.URLEncode() function.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: My code is in classic ASP, so I would like to see a way in ASP itself

Answer (score -1):

As stated, the [`UrlEncode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would be the way to go.

Some time ago I wrote [a small class `QueryString` to simplify the work with those query strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9053/A-Small-Class-for-Simplifying-the-Work-with-URL-Pa).

An example usage would be:

```
private void Page_Load(
    object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e )
{
    // Let the object fill itself 
    // with the parameters of the current page.
    QueryString qs = new QueryString();

    // Read a parameter from the QueryString object.
    string value1 = qs["name1"];

    // Now remove the parameter.
    qs.RemoveParameter( "name1" );

    // This has the same effect as RemoveParameter() method:
    qs["name1"] = null;

    // ... Further processing of the value1 variable ... 
}
```

You can fill the query string class and don't have to care whether to URL-encode the values, the class handles this internally for you.

Comment: My code is in classic ASP, so I would like to see a way in ASP itself