# "&" inside QueryString value

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

I'm using QueryStrings for users to auto-select values from a drop down list. Some of the values in this drop down list contain "&" in them.

E.g. "Acquisitions & Development"

When the user passes through a value with an "&", the string value gets cut off before the second half.

```
string functionalDepartment = Request.QueryString["FunctionalDepartment"];
//returns "Acquisitions "
```

Is there a way that I can include the second half of the value when getting the value from the QueryString?

Comment: You can also use ID's instead of the description. Now when your description changes, links break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & character needs to be URL encoded because & is used to divide the query string into name=value pairs. When *creating* the URL, use:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before passing it to query string just replace:

```
.Replace("&","%26");
```

or use Server.URLEncode()

Answer (score 1):

You could user `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` while setting the values for the drop down.

This will ensure that `&` will not break the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a  ampersand (&)  might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers.

More Details see this [Query strings with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579151/query-strings-with-special-characters)

I also refer that

Answer (score 0):

`Server.UrlEncode("url")` will solve ur issue.

Example:

```
 MyURL = "http://www.ursite.com/urpage.aspx?ReqStr=" + Server.UrlEncode("ASP.NET Examples");
```