# ASP classic page freeze with querystring containing value "etc.com?v0=%25n"

Tags: asp-classic, query-string, wildcard

I hosted a page on IIS(Internet Information Services). It's ASP classic.
Hosted on Window Server 2008.

```
<%
dim x
x = Trim(UCase(Request.QueryString("v0")))
if x= "" then
x="no value"
end if
response.write "<h1>Hello World "& x &"</h1>"
%>
```

Tried the following address, in Internet Explorer

Input address :

```
    "test/sample.asp?v0=%25ABC"
```

Result :

```
    "Hello World %ABC"
```

Input :

```
    "test/sample.asp"
```

Result :

```
    "Hello World No Value"
```

Input address :

```
    "test/sample.asp?v0=%25123"
```

Result :

```
    "Hello World %123"
```

Input address :

```
    "test/sample.asp?v0=%25n" or "test/sample.asp?v0=%25N"
```

Result :

```
Web browser stop working.
```

Is there any setting within IIS that causes this symptom? or any other causes?

Add-On - 2/11/2015

the actual coding is not really confidential. but its too long to be posted here. But the actual scenario is as follow:

User can search item using a `input box type text`, then `onblur` the input is forwarded to a function that call a `showmodaldialog.`

with the following sample:

```
javascript

window.showModalDialog("search_item.asp?v0="+input)
```

the input is URL encoded before sending forward.
The Users discovered that the "%" sign is actually a wildcard.
*don't really know how they found out.

So they have been using it ever since. However since we migrated the site to a
new server. The problem start to occur.

Thus I try to narrowed down the cause of the freezing and discovered that the value send was causing the problem.

I am not familiar with IIS. It could have been a mistake on my part while setting up the IIS.

Comment: Can you explain why your query string would have this value, and perhaps post code from the posting page? This sounds like a problem that would be solved by UrlEncode (see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9579151/3915817) but it is hard to know for sure without knowing the reason you need those characters and why they are in your url in the first place.

Comment: edited post with more sample, sorry for being to vague.
the new server is stil window server 2008 . New hardware instead. From IBM.

Comment: have you tried %25N on the old setup? Was there no error there?

Comment: Just got my old server running. I tried percent %25N on the old one, it work fine. Discovered something new. the browser (Internet explore) freeze up, however after I end task from task manager and restart the IE. I'm able to browse site like google and SO. but if I were to type in the URL for the test site .. its show page not found.

Comment: Could the problem be related to your wildcard function? What does this value ultimately get passed to? Sql Server? a JavaScript function?

Comment: the wild card is for oracle database. etc " item like '%n' "
the value is from HTML to Javascript to asp then lastly using asp ado to query from oracle database.

The sample I given above, using the sample.asp . I have tested it on both server. the old server work. the new one persist to have this symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day I finally found the reason that is causing the freezing. Its due to the antivirus!. 
The antivirus recognize querystring as an instrusion, thus blocking the IP.
Block period is 60 minutes by default. Cant attach picture but the details are as follows

Antivirus : Kaspersky Anti-Virus Suite for WKS and FS.

Security Type : Network Attack Blocker.

Network Attack Type : Intrusion.Win.EasyAddressWebServer.format-string.exploit

Currently looking for alternative to allow specific network instrusion.