# How to send '&' symbol in email subject/html body using mailgun API?

Tags: email, vbscript, asp-classic, html-email, mailgun

I have implemented **mailgun API method** to send emails throughout my site using classic ASP as said in this [link](https://gist.github.com/adamalesandro/e7821356128a551e7211). But when we try to send **'&' symbol** in the subject/text/htmlbody the text after **'&' symbol** are not sending in the email.

**For example : If we try to send subject as "A&B Traders" but the email sent using the mailgun API will show the subject as "A".**

Problem occurs due to we are sending the parameters using query string seperated by & to the mailgun API is there a way to bypass '&' symbol in the content and send in the query string value but it should be received as & in the email.

I searched a lot but can't able to find any solution in mailgun API documentation.

**Sample code to send email :**

```
Function SendMailSync(toAddress, fromAddress, subject, body, htmlBody)
Dim httpPostData
Dim mailGunMessageUrl
Const MAILGUN_BASE_URL = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{DOMAIN HERE}"
Const MAILGUN_API_KEY = "key-{API_KEY}"
httpPostData = "from=" & fromAddress
httpPostData = httpPostData & "&to=" & toAddress
httpPostData = httpPostData & "&subject=" & subject
httpPostData = httpPostData & "&text=" & body
httpPostData = httpPostData & "&html=" & htmlBody
set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
mailGunMessageUrl = MAILGUN_BASE_URL & "/messages"
http.Open "POST", mailGunMessageUrl, false, "api", MAILGUN_API_KEY
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
http.Send httpPostdata
If http.status <> 200 Then
    Response.Write "An error occurred: " & http.responseText
End If
SendMailSync = http.responseText
Set http = Nothing
End Function
SendMailSync "adam@example.com", "No Reply noreply@example.com", "A&B Traders", "A&B Traders Welcomes You", ""
```

Comment: Just `Server.UrlEncode()` each value you pass as a querystring.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would have been answered before, but can't find it so answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query strings with special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579151/query-strings-with-special-characters) *(although the quality of those answers isn't great, due to confusion over Classic ASP and .Net)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `SendMailAsync()` function so that you [`Server.UrlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx) each value passed. For example with the `subject`, just change it to;

```
httpPostData = httpPostData & "&subject=" & Server.UrlEncode(subject)
```

that way, when the URL is sent the `subject` query string parameter will look like;

```
&subject=A%26B%20Traders
```

If you want to test the approach yourself you can use an online URL decode / encode page like the [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Whenever manually sending data via a Http Request you should URL encode all parameters so things like conflicts with special characters like `?` and `&` etc don't happen. When you submit a standard form the Internet Browser does this as part of its process, which is why some may not be familiar with why it is required when sending manual requests.

---

#### Useful Links

- [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax - 2.2.  Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)
- [A: escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706649/692942) *(information about reserved characters)*.

Comment: @AspTeamDci it works for any data you need to pass. In fact, you should URL encode parameters in `GET` or `POST` method http requests as the Browser does by default with a standard HTML form.